# Add CSV to existing excel file without the need to select csv location

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I'm able to get a simple VBA script to auto import the csv information to my master list excel file. However, I will need to manually navigate to where the CSV file is store. How can I automate this process assuming there will not have any change in the the CSV location and file name. I am currently using the following VBA script. Any help will be appreciated.

Sub Append_CSV_File()

```
Dim csvFileName As Variant
Dim destCell As Range

Set destCell = Worksheets("master").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)      'CHANGE SHEET NAME

csvFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="CSV Files (*.csv),*.csv", Title:="Select a CSV File", MultiSelect:=False)
If csvFileName = False Then Exit Sub

With destCell.Parent.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & csvFileName, Destination:=destCell)
    .TextFileStartRow = 2
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With

destCell.Parent.QueryTables(1).Delete
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

You simply hard code the value of the variable `csvFileName`

i.e. change

```
csvFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(
FileFilter:="CSV Files (*.csv),*.csv", 
Title:="Select a CSV File", MultiSelect:=False)
```

to

```
csvFileName  = "C:\MyCSVFIle.CSV"
```

Comment: btw, if I want to add the csv as a wildcard, would this work? csvFileName  = "C:\*.CSV"??

Comment: No. You need to work out all the individual files that fit the wildcard and process them individually.